# ¿Como saco un valor en especifico de un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

buen día, en un ArrayList estoy guardando varios datos y entre esos datos esta materia_x_semestre, en donde el usuario primero ingresa cuantas materias ve y luego según el numero que puso va ingresando la cantidad de materias, una vez ingresado quisiera mostrar solamente las materias que ha registrado en materia_x_semestre, este es lo que tengo hasta ahora en mi clase principal y cada vez que lo ejecuto al final me sale error al momento de mostrar solo materia_x_semestre y ya no se que hacer.

```
package tarea_u2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TAREA_U2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombre, apellido, direccion, carrera, semestre, materia_x_semestre;
        int edad, telefono, contador;
        Estudiante objEstudiante;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\033[35mIntegrantes: \n\033[31m-Romero Vera Jorge Josue \n\033[31m-Curicama Salazar Lizeth Abigail");
        ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();

        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre: ");
        nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese apellido: ");
        apellido = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese Edad: ");
        edad = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese telefono: ");
        telefono = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese direccion: ");
        direccion = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese carrera: ");
        carrera = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el Semestre en que esta: ");
        semestre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("¿Cuantas materias que ve por Semestre?: ");
        contador = sc.nextInt();
        int cn = 0;
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int x = 0; x < contador; x++) {
            cn++;
            System.out.println("Materia #" + cn);
            materia_x_semestre = sc.nextLine();
            Estudiante est = new Estudiante(nombre, apellido, edad, telefono, direccion, carrera, semestre, materia_x_semestre, contador);

            lista.add(est.getMateria_x_semestre());

        }
      //Mostrar solo materia_x_semestre
        System.out.println("");
        for(int i = 0;i < lista.size();i++){
            Estudiante e;
            e=(Estudiante)lista.get(i);
            System.out.println("Materias: "+e.getMateria_x_semestre());
    //System.out.println(lista.get(i));      
    
}

    }
}
```

Comment: No sé si se trata de un ejercicio o de un problema real, pero la lógica es algo errónea. Por ejemplo, dentro del bucle creas cada vez una instancia de `Estudiante`, cuando se supone que el estudiante debería ser siempre el mismo. Ahí lo que deberías crear es una instancia de `Materia` que luego agregarías al array de materias que debería ser un miembro de la clase `Estudiante`. Luego, para mostrar las materias interarías sobre el array de materias del estudiante, no sobre el estudiante. Creo que debes re-organizar tu modelo de datos.

Comment: Incluso, en un modelo de datos bien montado, la lista de materias iría dentro de una clase `Semestre`, y `Estudiante` tendría un miembro que guardaría una lista de objetos de la clase `Semestre`. La relación entonces sería: `Estudiante -> Semestre (lista) -> Materia (lista)`

Answer (score 0):

El objeto estudiante tal vez seria mejor declararlo arriba y afuera del ciclo.
Por otro lado, en la lista, estas agregando lo que retorne el metodo `getMateria_x_semestre()`, no un objeto de tipo estudiante, probablemente lo que te da error es el cast. Tendrias que añadir a la lista el objeto estudiante y despues imprimir lo que retorne el metodo `getMateria_x_semestre()`. Te dejo un ejemplo de como quedaria esa ultima parte del codigo. Espero que te sirva

```
contador = sc.nextInt();
int cn = 0;
sc.nextLine();
Estudiante est = new Estudiante(nombre, apellido, edad, telefono, direccion, carrera, semestre, materia_x_semestre, contador); // creas el objeto estudiante
for (int x = 0; x < contador; x++) { // le añadis las materias
    cn++;
    System.out.println("Materia #" + cn);
    materia_x_semestre = sc.nextLine();
    est.addMateriaPorSemestre(materia_x_semestre); // podrias crear un metodo parecido a este en la clase Estudiante
}
lista.add(est); // añadis el objeto a la lista

//Mostrar solo materia_x_semestre
System.out.println("");
Estudiante e = lista.get(0); // para evitarte el cast, cuando creas la lista le podrias especificar que se van a almacenar solo objetos de tipo Estudiante. Se hace asi: ArrayList<Estudiante> lista = new ArrayList();
System.out.println("Materias: " + e.getMateria_x_semestre()); // imprimis las materias por semestre.
```

En el ejemplo solo mostre lo que contenia el primer elemento de la lista, si tuvieras muchos estudiantes podrias recorrerla de dos maneras diferentes, aca te dejo ambas opciones:

```
lista.forEach(estudiante -> {
    System.out.println("Materias: " + estudiante.getMateria_x_semestre());
});
```

---

```
for(int = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
    Estudiante estudiante = lista.get(i);
    System.out.println("Materias: " + e.getMateria_x_semestre());
}
```